# CodePipeline StackSet integration fails wtth ValidationException because of role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

Recentry CodePipeline introduced CloudFormation StackSet integration ( https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-codepipeline-supports-deployments-with-cloudformation-stacksets/ ). I'm trying to build a pipeline that deploys stack set but pipeline action fails with message:

> An API call to CloudFormation.UpdateStackSet (RequestId: {ID}) returned a ValidationError error: You must provide an administration role ARN with the correct PassRole permission to perform an update operation on this StackSet.

The stack set is already there and the roles are working fine, I'm just trying to bind the deployment into CodePipeline using new integration feature (using same roles).

My pipeline role is allowed to pass stack set administration role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<ID>:role/infrastructure-v1-organiz-StackSetAdministratorRol-1Q81WRE9ZGNAT"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the role that is used by stack set:

[image]

And this role is being passed by codepipeline:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted AWS support - it is a limitation (broken in my opinion) of CodePipeline-CloudFormation integration. CodePipeline enforces using very particular values (where CloudFormation does not need that - we have stack set deployed in early 2019 and it's impossible to provision it with current CodePipeline integration).

I issued a feature request to loosen this validation.

Answer (score 1):

This part all seems right, but I can't tell if you are making use of the [CloudFormationStackSet Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-StackSets.html#action-reference-StackSet-example)

Also, you don't mention if it is being used with the organization. If this is the case, you need to enable it in your organizational settings.

[image: Enable Stacksets]

Comment: What you mention is required for auto-deploy feature of stack set that uses organizational units (so called service-managed access). With self-managed (roles created by hand) this is not needed. But yes, we have this feature enabled.